# tests for an application that only has webforms that read and insert and data using sql server stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello (i dont have any expirience on tests). There is a Web Applicaction that only has web forms, that print data read from stored procedures, and insert data using stored procedures as well. All the business logic is in the stored procedures. I have to say i dont like the way the application was done, but is mandatory to have as much tests as possible. Most of the methods return void (becouse they are for instance a button_clicked method that read from text boxes and call the stored procedure, the stored procedure does everything) So i cant do unit testing. Could you recommend me some tests that i can do and document, that fits to this web application please? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If most of your business logic sits in stored procedures, it's best that you implement some tests for your procs.
Have a look at the TST Framework for testing your sql.

http://tst.codeplex.com/

As for the website, what you can do is probably ensure that you are calling the correct stored procedures on the invocation of some buttons.

e.g. you don't want to call the "ChangeName" stored procedure when the "Calculate Monthly Salary" button is clicked.